# Shake an object back and forth with easing at the end?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I almost want a jarring animation, such that it shakes back and forth rapidly for a second, and then slows back down, easing back into its normal position. There are tons of answers for just continues shaking, but how would I decrease the shake? Would I `Lerp` really fast, or use `PingPong` with a function that slows?

Comment: Sprite renderer specifically, but am I able to just move the entire GameObject?

Comment: Um... I waited 3600 moments.

Comment: Oh, OK then. Thanks.

Comment: 7200 more moments waited.

Comment: Shhh. It's already fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply can simply shake a GameObject with by getting the original position then in a coroutine function, do `YourObjTransform.position = defaultPos + UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitSphere * shakeAmount;` in a while loop for a certain time. After shaking the GameObject, reset the value back to its default position.

As for decreasing the shake, you do `shakeAmount += Time.deltaTime;` in the while loop. This will decrease the shake speed in the while loop.

The function below is a complete example of the above statement. It takes three parameters, the GameObject to shake, how long to shake the GameObject and what time to start decreasing the shake.

For example,if you pass in `myGameOBject`, `5f`, `3f` to the function, it will shake the `myGameOBject` for a total time of `5` seconds. While shaking the `myGameOBject` and the counter reaches `3`, it will start to decrease the speed(`shakeAmount`) of the shake until timer reaches `5`.

Pass `true` to the last parameter if the GameObject to shake is a `SpriteRender` so that the z axis won't move and it will only rotate in Z axis when shaking.

```
public GameObject GameObjectToShake;
bool shaking = false;

IEnumerator shakeGameObjectCOR(GameObject objectToShake, float totalShakeDuration, float decreasePoint, bool objectIs2D = false)
{
    if (decreasePoint >= totalShakeDuration)
    {
        Debug.LogError("decreasePoint must be less than totalShakeDuration...Exiting");
        yield break; //Exit!
    }

    //Get Original Pos and rot
    Transform objTransform = objectToShake.transform;
    Vector3 defaultPos = objTransform.position;
    Quaternion defaultRot = objTransform.rotation;

    float counter = 0f;

    //Shake Speed
    const float speed = 0.1f;

    //Angle Rotation(Optional)
    const float angleRot = 4;

    //Do the actual shaking
    while (counter < totalShakeDuration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        float decreaseSpeed = speed;
        float decreaseAngle = angleRot;

        //Shake GameObject
        if (objectIs2D)
        {
            //Don't Translate the Z Axis if 2D Object
            Vector3 tempPos = defaultPos + UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitSphere * decreaseSpeed;
            tempPos.z = defaultPos.z;
            objTransform.position = tempPos;

            //Only Rotate the Z axis if 2D
            objTransform.rotation = defaultRot * Quaternion.AngleAxis(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-angleRot, angleRot), new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f));
        }
        else
        {
            objTransform.position = defaultPos + UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitSphere * decreaseSpeed;
            objTransform.rotation = defaultRot * Quaternion.AngleAxis(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-angleRot, angleRot), new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f));
        }
        yield return null;


        //Check if we have reached the decreasePoint then start decreasing  decreaseSpeed value
        if (counter >= decreasePoint)
        {
            Debug.Log("Decreasing shake");

            //Reset counter to 0 
            counter = 0f;
            while (counter <= decreasePoint)
            {
                counter += Time.deltaTime;
                decreaseSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(speed, 0, counter / decreasePoint);
                decreaseAngle = Mathf.Lerp(angleRot, 0, counter / decreasePoint);

                Debug.Log("Decrease Value: " + decreaseSpeed);

                //Shake GameObject
                if (objectIs2D)
                {
                    //Don't Translate the Z Axis if 2D Object
                    Vector3 tempPos = defaultPos + UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitSphere * decreaseSpeed;
                    tempPos.z = defaultPos.z;
                    objTransform.position = tempPos;

                    //Only Rotate the Z axis if 2D
                    objTransform.rotation = defaultRot * Quaternion.AngleAxis(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-decreaseAngle, decreaseAngle), new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f));
                }
                else
                {
                    objTransform.position = defaultPos + UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitSphere * decreaseSpeed;
                    objTransform.rotation = defaultRot * Quaternion.AngleAxis(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-decreaseAngle, decreaseAngle), new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f));
                }
                yield return null;
            }

            //Break from the outer loop
            break;
        }
    }
    objTransform.position = defaultPos; //Reset to original postion
    objTransform.rotation = defaultRot;//Reset to original rotation

    shaking = false; //So that we can call this function next time
    Debug.Log("Done!");
}


void shakeGameObject(GameObject objectToShake, float shakeDuration, float decreasePoint, bool objectIs2D = false)
{
    if (shaking)
    {
        return;
    }
    shaking = true;
    StartCoroutine(shakeGameObjectCOR(objectToShake, shakeDuration, decreasePoint, objectIs2D));
}

void Start()
{
    shakeGameObject(GameObjectToShake, 5, 3f, false);
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! I'll check this out ASAP and let you know if it works. Thanks again.

Comment: You can decrease `speed` and `angleRot` variables  if the shaking is too much. It includes rotation too to make it more realistic as shaking rotates an object a little bit. This is tested with a cube(3D), if you want to use this a 2D object like sprite, you have to modify it a little bit and make sure that the z axis does not change. It's very simple to do that. You also have to comment the rotation codes as you don't need that with 2D Objects.

Comment: Yeah, I'll definitely edit it very slightly to work with my 2D project. It's awesome you made it so customizable.

Comment: Yes, I like re-usable codes. So this one is going into my archive. I did a test and came to conclusion that `angleRot`  is better when set to `4`. So I think you should change that. Edited the code with that. Let me know if there is a problem.

Comment: Fixed rotation bug and added optional parameter for SpriteRenderer(2D objects).  When `true` is passed to it, it will make it work specifically for 2D objects.