# Camera shaking - my lerptime is not taken into account

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code that is supposed to do some camera shaking and do that without pauses, meaning the movement is constant between the given new positions. 
I do that by giving random values for the new rotation and new location, then gradually move towards them along the given time. When that time expires, the `coroutine` starts over by fetching another new time again.

```
IEnumerator CamShake(float time)
{
    while (shakingContinues)
    {
        newPos = basePosition + new Vector3(Random.Range(-1.0f * deltaPos, deltaPos), Random.Range(-1.0f * deltaPos, deltaPos));
        newRot = Quaternion.Euler(baseRotation.x,
            baseRotation.y + Random.Range(-1.0f * deltaRotDegree, deltaRotDegree), baseRotation.z + Random.Range(-1.0f*deltaRotDegree, deltaRotDegree));
        float lastTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        float timer = 0.0f;

        while (timer < time)
        {
            transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localPosition, newPos, timer / time);
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.localRotation, newRot, timer / time);

            //spr.color = new Color(spr.color.r, spr.color.g, spr.color.b, Mathf.Lerp(start, end, timer / time));
            timer += (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - lastTime);
            lastTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
            //if (timer >= time)
            //{
            //    timer = 0.0f;
            //}
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that I have no other functions being called for this reason, so no conflicting functions are here. The coroutine is called only once.
It is called like this:

```
void LateUpdate ()
{
    if (!alreadyStarted)
    {
        alreadyStarted = true;
        //StartCoroutine(GetNewValues());
        StartCoroutine(CamShake(lerpTime));
    }
}
```

Edit: This shake, I use it on a cam that has a smooth follow on it as well so I shake along the local transform.
I also want it to be smooth as the player will have to orient using the camera, I just want it to be a wee bit more difficult to get by.

Comment: `Lerp` is not a good way to shake a GameObject. Use `Random.insideUnitSphere`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39383000/3785314) is a complete method to shake any GameObject over time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shake an object back and forth with easing at the end?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380901/shake-an-object-back-and-forth-with-easing-at-the-end)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. By the way mine would - and I think should - work, but so is life.

Comment: Note: You can use Time.deltaTime inside a coroutine. This avoids the floating point precision issues that you'll run into with Time.realtimeSinceStartup after a few hours of operation.

Comment: @Programmer I finally tried your link, it's fine, but my code needs the following:
 - shake using local transform (the cam has a smoothfollow on it already)
 - don't shake it crazily, I just want it to be a wee bit more dofficoult for the player to focus. as a consequence to slower shake, I need it to be smooth to avoid being disorienting. I will add this to the original question as I wasn't clear there.